# Are there any tax-advantaged retirement plans I can use if I'm a grad student with only stipend/fellowship income?

Tags: united-states, taxes, retirement, education

I'm starting a graduate program in 2017 where I'll get a stipend. I don't think I'll receive a W2 because I won't be working for the wages, so I don't think I can contribute to my IRAs while I'm in school. Obviously there is no 401K either, traditional or Roth.

Do I have any options for saving for retirement in a tax-advantaged way? I know I can just use a brokerage or savings account, but I'm talking about options where either the money is contributed pre-tax or the earnings aren't taxable, like a traditional or Roth IRA/401K.

Also I'm not worried about liquidity or anything like that, so the [sources](http://ask.metafilter.com/231887/Saving-for-retirement-as-a-graduate-student) I find that say "don't save for retirement as a grad student because you'll need the money while you're in school" aren't relevant to my situation. I'm specifically asking about what vehicles are available to me for tax-advantaged retirement savings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're single, the only solution I'm aware of, assuming you are truly getting a 1099-misc and not a W-2 (and don't have a W-2 option available, like TAing), is to save in a nondeductible account for now.

Then, when you later do have a job, use that nondeductible account (in part) to fund your retirement accounts.  Particularly the first few years (if you're a "young" grad student in particular), you'll probably be low enough on the income side that you can fit this in - in particular if you've got a 401k or 403b plan at work; make your from-salary contributions there, and make deductible IRA or Roth IRA contributions from your in-school savings.

If you're not single, or even if you are single but have a child, you have a few other options.

Spouses who don't have earned income, but have a spouse who does, can set up a [Spousal IRA](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p590a/ch01.html#en_US_2015_publink1000230412).  You can then, combined, save up to your *spouse*'s total earned income (or the usual per-person maximums).  So if you are married and your wife/husband works, you can essentially count his/her earned income towards your earned income.

Second, if you have a child, consider setting up a [529 plan](https://www.irs.gov/uac/529-Plans:-Questions-and-Answers) for them.  You're probably going to want to do this anyway, right?  You can even do this for a niece or nephew, if you're feeling generous.

Comment: I'm in my mid 30's and married, so a spousal IRA may be the way to go. To clarify, this means that a) if I earn 0 and my wife earns 50K, she can contribute 5500 to her IRA and I can contribute 5500 to my spousal IRA, or b) we can contribute 5500 total between the two of us to each of our IRA's? Will the fact that I already have several pre-existing IRA's cause problems? Maybe I should ask this in a separate question.

Comment: [From what I can find](http://www.moneycrashers.com/spousal-ira-rules-eligibility/), it looks like a) is correct (that the spouse can contribute 5500 to his/her account and 5500 to the spousal account).

Comment: a) is correct indeed; you each can contribute up to the maximum.  More specifically, she can contribute as she normally can, and you have a separate (but identical) limit under the Kay Bailey Hutchinson Spousal IRA act.  (I suppose they're not guaranteed forever to be identical.)

Comment: Also note that in this case, you should be aware of potential limitations if she has a 401k and your income is above a certain level.

Comment: Good to know, thank you. Her income will be 50K or less while I'm in school, so I don't think we'll run into any income limits, but I'll look into that.

Comment: You could start a SEP IRA, if your 1099 income is considered self-employed income.

Comment: @quid Unfortunately, fellowship income is only considered earned income if it's reported on a W-2.

Comment: Will he not owe self-employment taxes?

Comment: No - see [this question](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/13971/graduate-student-stipend-1099-misc-taxes-seem-to-be-coming-out-too-high-am-i-do) for example.

Comment: Yale has a [great table](http://tax.yale.edu/2015-federal-and-state-ct-tax-treatment-certain-payments-made-yale-university) showing the various taxabilities of student employment.

Comment: @Joe interesting, I wasn't aware!